# Difference between shuffle partition and repartition

Tags: apache-spark, partitioning

I am a newbie in spark and I am trying to understand shuffle partition and repartition function. But i still dont understand how they are different. Both reduces the number of partition??

Thank you

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The biggest difference between shuffle partition and repartition is when things are defined.

The configuration `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions` is a property and according to the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-performance-tuning.html#other-configuration-options)

> Configures the number of partitions to use when shuffling data for joins or aggregations.

That means, every time you run a Join or any type of aggregation in spark that will shuffle the data according to the configuration, where the default value is 200. So if you join two datasets the number of partitions in the shuffle will be 200.

The `repartition(numPartitions, *cols)` function is applied during an execution, where you can define how many partitions you will write, that usually is for output writing based in partition columns or just number. The [example](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.repartition.html) in the documentation is pretty good to show.

So in general, Shuffle Partition is for Joins and Aggregations during the execution. Repartition is for number of output files, based in number or partition column.

Comment: So is it correct to assume that stages before the shuffle will not have 200 partition but it changes when it starts next stage having shuffle.

Comment: Usually the first Map step has the same number of partitions as your source. If that contains multiple files that fit inside of the partition it will have the same number of partitions as your files.